# Find order of the poles

Tags: complex-analysis

Find order of the poles in $z_0=0$

> a) $f(z)=\cot z$

$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} z \cot z=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} z \frac{\cos z}{\sin z}=1$ and $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} z^2 \cot z=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} z^2 \frac{\cos z}{\sin z}=0$

So $f$ has a pole of order $1$ in $0$.

> b) $f(z)=\frac{\sin^2z}{z^4}$

$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} z^2 \frac{\sin^2z}{z^4}=1$ and $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} z^3 \frac{\sin^2z}{z^4}=0$

So the pole is of order $2$.

> c) $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}\cot z - \frac{1}{z^4}$

$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} z^4 (\frac{1}{z^2}\cot z - \frac{1}{z^4})=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} z^2\frac{\cos z}{\sin z} - 1=-1$ and $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} z^5 (\frac{1}{z^2}\cot z - \frac{1}{z^4})=0$,

So pole is of order $4$.

Are my answers correct?

Comment: Yup. $${}{}{}{}{}{}$$

Comment: They are correct, but you don't need to check the second limit. What you need to do, for instance in the first one, is to check that $\lim \limits_{z\rightarrow 0} (z \cot (z))$ exists finitely and that $\lim \limits_{z\rightarrow 0} (\cot (z))$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Why? And $\lim \limits_{z\rightarrow 0} (\cot (z))$ exists in $\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$ as far as I know...

Comment: @luka5z Why? Because that's what the definition of pole requires you to do. I should have said that $\lim \limits_{z\rightarrow 0} (\cot (z))$ doesn't exist finitely.

Comment: Yes, now it makes sense to me. I thought you were talking that this limit doesnt exist (is not defined).